# Question closed before moderators could think about it

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I've just noticed that [my question was closed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-separate-egg-whites). Why is it off limits to propose a question asking for the best way to do something that would obviously require energy to be spent. I want to know what is the most efficient way to separate eggs. How is that any worse than [this stupid question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/770/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-destroy-the-universe), which is not just on the same lines but destructive too.

Maybe in the future all closed questions for physics.stackexchange.com should be brought up in meta first.

Answer (score 4):

I can see you put some effort into your question, that does not justify your behaviour. It is OK to appeal here when your question is closed, but you loose the right to be taken seriously when you start calling other questions stupid.

Your question is fairly good, in a grammatical sense, but is terrible in a physical sense. You didn't actually ask anything physical. In fact, it's not clear at all what you were asking. I only understood what you were looking for after reading the comments.

If you had given some examples in your answers (of what physics has to do with it, such as buoyancy or a centrifuge) it might have worked a little better. You can try editing it, but I can't guarantee that it'll be reopen.

And the fact that it was closed without moderator assistance is not something to complain about, it just shows how "off" your question was.

Comment: And the other question you linked to is a very poor question as well. I down voted it myself.

Comment: Evan *can* be a valuable contributor (he's written some primo answers on SO), but he also has a long, *long* history of poking at various SOFUE sites with sticks to see what they do. He's been penalty boxed more than once, and Jeff felt it was necessary to contact him by telephone in hopes of understanding what he was up to. I won't advocate total banination or anything extreme like that, but I don't feel the need to cut him much slack.